# JSON Object Formatting using Powershell for http request

Tags: json, powershell, object

I am working on a project integrating with Slack and I am having some trouble when I am trying to send data to the API as it is expecting a Json object for the blocks that it is needing to format.

Using the Slack Block Builder I know it is expecting:

```
    "blocks": [        
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "http://bar.com"
            }
        }
    ]
```

And this is how I am trying to construct the object and the parameters for the `chat.postMessage` method to send to the API

```
$messageText = 'http://bar.com'
$blocksDetailObj = [PSCustomObject]@{'type' = '"mrkdwn"'
                     'text' = $messageText}


$blocksObject = [PSCustomObject]@{ 'type' = '"section"'
                   'text' = $blocksDetailObj }

$blocksArray = @()

$blocksArray += $blocksObject

$queryStringParameters = @{ 'token' = $botToken 
                            'channel' = $channelID
                            'text' = 'fallback text'
                            'blocks' = $blocksArray 
                                     }
```

Any help or documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may want to checkout [PSSlack](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSSlack) - a PS module to interact with the Slack API.

Comment: Or PoshBot https://github.com/poshbotio/PoshBot

Comment: Was any of the answers helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to checkout [PSSlack](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSSlack) - a PS module to interact with the Slack API, or [PoshBot](https://github.com/poshbotio/PoshBot), as suggested. [Here](http://ramblingcookiemonster.github.io/PSSlack/) you can find a long blog post that gives context how to PSSlack can be used.

If you do not want to use those modules directly you should take a look at the [`Send-SlackMessage` function](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSSlack/blob/master/PSSlack/Public/Send-SlackMessage.ps1):

> ```
> $body = @{ }
>
>     switch ($psboundparameters.keys)
>     {
>         'channel'     {$body.channel = $channel }
>         'text'        {$body.text     = $text}
>         'username'    {$body.username = $username}
>         'asuser'      {$body.as_user = $AsUser}
>         'iconurl'     {$body.icon_url = $iconurl}
>         'iconemoji'   {$body.icon_emoji   = $iconemoji}
>         'linknames'   {$body.link_names = 1}
>         'parse'       {$body.parse = $Parse}
>         'UnfurlLinks' {$body.unfurl_links = $UnfurlLinks}
>         'UnfurlMedia' {$body.unfurl_media = $UnfurlMedia}
>         'attachments' {$body.attachments = $Attachments}
>     }
>     $Messages += $Body
> }
> else
> {
>     foreach($Message in $SlackMessage)
>     {
>         $Messages += $SlackMessage
>     }
> }
>
>
> foreach($Message in $Messages)
> {
>     if($Token -or ($Script:PSSlack.Token -and -not $Uri))
>     {
>         if($Message.attachments)
>         {
>             $Message.attachments = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject     @$Message.attachments) -Depth 6 -Compress
>         }
>
>         Write-Verbose "Send-SlackApi -Body $($Message | Format-List | Out-String)"
>         $response = Send-SlackApi @ProxyParam -Method chat.postMessage -Body $Message -Token $Token -ForceVerbose:$ForceVerbose
>
>         if ($response.ok)
>         {
>             $link = "$($Script:PSSlack.ArchiveUri)/$($response.channel)/p$($response.ts -replace '\.')"
>             $response | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name link -Value $link
>         }
>
>         $response
>     }
>     elseif($Uri -or $Script:PSSlack.Uri)
>     {
>         if(-not $ForceVerbose) {
>             $ProxyParam.Add('Verbose', $False)
>         }
>         if($ForceVerbose) {
>             $ProxyParam.Add('Verbose', $true)
>         }
>         $json = ConvertTo-Json -Depth 6 -Compress -InputObject $Message
>         Invoke-RestMethod @ProxyParam -Method Post -Body $json -Uri $Uri
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         Throw 'No Uri or Token specified.  Specify a Uri or Token in the parameters or via Set-PSSlackConfig'
>     }
> }
> ```